# How to organize images (several) for use in Android app?

Tags: android, image

Just started with Android, and I have a question about handling images.

I'm thinking of creating a simple quiz app with images as well for each question. Let say if it is 100 questions, I need to have 100 images, one for each. Where would you add the images, and how would you retrieve them for each question?

Comment: No research effort. "Tell me how to use it, store and retrieve it, tell me where to put and everything in between". I believe we should do our homework before asking.

Comment: @David: Absolutely agree with you, it's very basic and there are many information out there about it

Comment: You may think that, but I was looking for an answer like @KasperMoerch.  That explains why I should do that (not about details of how). Why not give a link or hint instead of saying that there is lot of information "out there"..? Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a quite a few things you could do:

1. Add all the images to `res/drawable`. This will however, depending on the size of the images cause your APK-file to increase in size and it's not very flexible should you want to add/remove questions at a later point.
2. If you have a webservice at your disposal, from which you could download the images, you could download the images to a specific folder on the device and load them into the app from there. This would also make the app more versatile when removing/adding questions.
3. Same as nr. 2 - but you save the images in a database on the device.

**Number 1** is probably the easiest to use - but will require an update of the app whenever you add/remove questions.

**Number 2/3** would be preferable in my opinion, but would also require that you have the needed webservice availible for use.

Comment: Thank you, I got the points I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have many solutions for it,

Put images in  1. `res/drawable` 2. in `/asset`. 3. `on WebServer`

**Choice is depends on the using situations and size of images and also your choice is too. :-)**

Answer (score 0):

Put images in `res/drawable` and retrieve them with `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the images in res/drawable  in ur eclipse project 
and ur drawable  will allow you  png,jpg,bitmap formats and may be more i guess

and to retrive thesee u can retrive  it by

`LinearLayout= new LinearLAyout(this)
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.imagename);
LL.addView(iv);
setContentView(ll)`;

Answer (score 0):

Put images in `res/drawable`. Create an integer array and store resource values of 100 images.
you can retrieve each images using `getResources().getDrawable(intArray[index])`